# Appengine run endpoint request on specific instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I'm running an app on appengine with a paid account and a resident instance. The first endpoint request after the warmup request is really slow (6-12 seconds) every other request takes about 300ms. Thus, I would like to add an endpoint request into a servlet that is started by the warmup request.
The problem that I have with this solution is that the request is not necessarily consumed by the recently started instance but can be consumed by another instance.
Therefore I created a url that is specific to the instance that is in the warmup phase:

```
ModulesService modulesApi = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService();
String currentInstance = modulesApi.getCurrentInstanceId();
String currentModule = modulesApi.getCurrentModule();
String currentVersion = modulesApi.getCurrentVersion();
String instanceUrl = "https://"+currentInstance+"-dot-"+currentVersion+"-dot-"+currentModule+"-dot-"+Constants.APP_ENGINE_URL;
```

The url works and I can access the index.html. However, I'm not able to access the endpoints.
For example, I have an endpoint called testEndpoint and would like to access a method called warmup:
I tried to use
_ah/api/testEndpoint/v1/warmup
as well as _ah/spi/com.test.backend.apis.TestEndpoint.warmup

None of them works.

Comment: No need to build your own logic to add code to the warm-up request. App Engine has ways for that, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_Warmup_requests . If you must to execute endpoint code during warm-up i suggest you do it through code and not via HTTP requests, that could cause another warm-up.

Comment: I know that app engine has its own warmup. That's why I wrote that the first request after the warmup takes such a long time. The first request time doesn't get better by executing all the methods that are inside the endpoint with my own warmup. I have to send a request might be due to dns stuff?